# Acesso remoto ao banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, servidor, redes

Tenho um BD dentro de uma rede corporativa em uma maquina local servindo de servidor MySQL.

A estrutura da rede funciona assim!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso acessar por exemplo a maquina que está marcada de vermelho, e neste ambiente o "Servidor" tem seu IP estático "10.10.10.10", e a maquina marcada "192.168.0.34".

Alguém poderia me ajudar como fazer pra conseguir acessar esse servidor Mysql?

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma regra no servidor...que faça o nateamento da faixa 10.10.10.x para 192.168.0.x no firewall ou alguma regra que faça o redirecionamento de uma conexao na porta do mysql no servidor para o computador de destino, também é preciso fazer uma configuração no apache para aceitar essa conexao.

Comment: Teria algum material que ajude a fazer este mapeamento? Eu fiz alguns comandos la no servidor... "C:\ netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=179.111.X.X listenport=3306 connectport=3306 connectaddress=192.168.X.X", depois tentei a conexão mas não deu certo.

Comment: na pergunta não fala nada sobre qual dificuldade você está tendo. Dá algum erro ao tentar conectar?

Comment: Sim o erro que aparece é, ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP SERVIDOR' (10060).

Comment: Tentou fazer o que descrevi na minha resposta? -> Criar um usuário com permissão de acessar o MySql de outro IP.

Comment: Eu usei o comando para acesso ao Mysql, mysql -uroot -p<senha> -h<ipdoservidor>. Criei o usuário com acesso a tudo, deixei com o "%" e mesmo assim quando tento fazer o acesso da a mensagem que citei acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta está relacionada a redes, olhando a sua figura você possui um servidor na ponta, certamente você está efetuando NAT dos seus ips da rede interna para que todos os seus computadores internos possam fazer acesso para a Internet.

Seu Servidor possui duas interfaces, uma que sai para a internet e a outra que deve servir como gateway para os computadores da rede 192.168.0.0/24, Acontece que o IP estático que está na sua interface wan  (10.10.10.10) não é um IP público então é bem provável que tenha um router na outra ponta, para fazer isso funcionar corretamente eu recomendo que esse router esteja em modo bridge, isso irá entregar um IP público (estático ou não, depende do contrato do seu link) diretamente na interface wan do seu servidor!

Com essa etapa concluída você deve fazer uma regra de redirecionamento no seu firewall, essa regra ira abrir na interface Wan a porta do seu Mysql e redirecionar a conexão para a máquina que tem o mysql rodando na sua rede interna.

Deste modo quando alguém fizer um acesso de fora da sua rede para o IP público do seu link na porta específica a conexão será redirecionada para o IP interno na porta específica.

(user na internet) -----> (conexão no IP Publico e porta mysql do seu link) ---> (redirecionamento para o IP e porta do PC na sua rede interna)

Comment: Então... eu até uso algumas coias para acesso externo, fiz umas configuração de redirecionamento do firewall e mesmo assim quando tendo acessar me da erro de porta fechada. Acredito que seja algum problema com o firewall.